# I can't seem to pip install anything at this point

Tags: pandas, installation, error-code

I'm very new to coding so I'm not really sure what I'm even reading in the terminal. But, I've been trying to install pandas and keep getting error code 1. So I came here and tried a couple of things I saw.

```
pip install --upgradesetuptools
```

This returns the same error code. then I tried, `pip install ez_setup`, that installed just fine. I tried pandas once more, the same error code. so finally I tried `pip install unroll`, then `easy_install -U setuptools`, neither of which worked. error code 1 followed by [Win error 5] access denied etc..

I wanted to copy/paste some of the code/error messages but it's a lot and I'm not sure what would even be helpful. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. Your questions can be formatted so it's easier for other folks to help; 2. Include at least the part of error message that you think is potentially helpful for debugging; 3.  What does "access denied etc" mean? If its a user privilege error, ensure you have the right privilege or use "sudo pip install pandas" to see if it works (sudo = super user privilege)

Comment: install python and using `pip` in a windows environment can be tricky. I would recommend install python and packages through anaconda or miniconda